# PHP Constructor and Dependencies Shorthand

Tags: php, dependency-injection, soa

As more and more service oriented PHP is being done these days, I find myself with a lot of PHP files that have this long chunk of code just for initialization. In other languages like C++ or typescript you can do the following without all the duplication. A PHP example:

```
namespace Test\Controllers;
use Test\Services\AppleService;
use Test\Services\BananaService;
use Test\Services\PearService;
use Test\Services\LemonService;
use Test\Services\PeachService;

class TestController{

    protected $appleService;
    protected $bananaService;
    protected $lemonService;
    protected $pearService;
    protected $peachService;

    public function __construct(
    AppleService $appleService,
    BananaService $bananaService,
    LemonService $lemonService,
    PearService $pearService,
    PeachService $peachService
    ){
        $this->appleService = $appleService;
        $this->bananaService = $bananaService;
        $this->lemonService = $lemonService;
        $this->pearService = $pearService;
        $this->peachService = $peachService;
    }
}
```

A Typescript Example:

```
module namespace Test.Controllers {
    export class TestController{
        constructor(
        private appleService:Test.Services.AppleService,
        private bananaService:Test.Services.BananaService,
        private lemonService:Test.Services.LemonService,
        private pearService:Test.Services.PearService,
        private peachService:Test.Services.PeachService
        ){}
    }
}
```

Are there better/shorter ways to do the same thing, and/or is any support to make this easier planned for upcoming PHP releases?

Comment: Dependency Injection Containers, like Pimple?

Comment: @MarkBaker That deals with instantiation not defining. Plus pimple is more of a service locator then a DI Container.... still useful though.

Comment: I think you are stuck with this. The only abbreviation that I can offer is that you can drop the use statements for favor of using namespaced class names but I don't believe it's a meaningful improvement.  As @MarkBaker stated DI Containers/Service Locators can ease the pain of creating and managing instances.

Comment: I'm aware of dependency injection containers. However, to make my code more testable I'd rather not work with injecting a whole container. Property injection feels like hacking to me. Aren't there any plans for PHP5.5+ to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative, property injection:

```
use DI\Annotation\Inject;

class TestController
{
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var AppleService
     */
    private $appleService;
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var BananaService
     */
    private $bananaService;
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var LemonService
     */
    private $lemonService;
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var PearService
     */
    private $pearService;
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var PeachService
     */
    private $peachService;
}
```

Is that shorter, or simpler to write? I'll let you judge. But I love it, I don't end up with a bloated constructor. This is inspired from Java/Spring FYI.

Now this example works with [PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.io/PHP-DI/) (disclaimer: I work on that), but there may be other DI containers that offer the same functionality.

**WARNING**: property injection doesn't fit everywhere.

I find it appropriate for controllers (since controllers are not supposed to be reused). [Read more here](http://en.mnapoli.fr/controllers-as-services/).

I don't think it would be appropriate to use it in services. So that's not the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This syntactic sugar will finally arrive in PHP 8.0 (November 26, 2020).

By prefixing arguments in the contructor with `public`, `protected` or `private`, they will be copied to and defined as class properties with the same name.

In PHP 8.0 the example of OP can be written as:

```
namespace Test\Controllers;

use Test\Services\AppleService;
use Test\Services\BananaService;
use Test\Services\PearService;
use Test\Services\LemonService;
use Test\Services\PeachService;

class TestController{

   public function __construct(
       protected AppleService $appleService,
       protected BananaService $bananaService,
       protected LemonService $lemonService,
       protected PearService $pearService,
       protected PeachService $peachService
   ){
   }
}
```

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion

https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8